# OnTap not working in children wrap on flutter

Tags: flutter, ontap

The OnTap I created in children wrap doesn't work, only the first children can be pasted Gesturedoctor OnTap and it works, but the next children when installed Gesture doctor doesn't work,

here's my code:

```
child: Wrap(
                children: [
                   GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("Test");
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeEditProfil);
                      },
                      child: SelectOptionProfil(),
                    ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("Test");
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                          context, routeEditProfil);
                    },
                    child: SelectOptionProfil(
                      icon: Icons.settings,
                      option: "Setting Password",
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap:(){
                       Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeAboutUs);
                     },
                    child: SelectOptionProfil(
                      icon: FontAwesomeIcons.users,
                      sizeIcon: 30,
                      widthSizedBox: 50,
                      option: "About Us",
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                     onTap:(){
                       Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeAboutUs);
                     },
                    child: SelectOptionProfil(
                      isIcon: false,
                      imageIcon: "assets/images/profile/icon_faq.png",
                      option: "FAQ",
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      _showDialogLogout(context);
                    },
                    child: SelectOptionProfil(
                      icon: Icons.logout,
                      option: "Logout",
                      isLogout: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Please help me for this problem, Thank you very much :)

Comment: your code work fine. you have just some `,` issue, I updated your question

Comment: when i have added ( , ) still onTap still not working